# Display text at an angle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I am writing an app for the iPad/iPhone and am looking for a suggestion on how I would go about displaying text at an arbitrary angle on the iPhone and iPad using xCode?

Thanks for the advice.

Best,
Tony

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `transform` property of any `UIView`—such as, in this case, a `UILabel`—to adjust its rotation, among many other things. For example:

```
myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(30 * M_PI / 180.0);
```

would rotate your label by 30 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for but just add the text to a UILabel:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
label.text = @"Some Text";
```

and then add a transform to the label to rotate it to whichever arbitrary angle you desire:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(someAngleInRadians);
[self.view addSubview:label]; 
[label release];
```

Just set the value for **someAngleInRadians** to the angle you wish to rotate the text to (in radians of course).

Cheers